# TikZ: Interference between polyglossia and `quotes` library

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, polyglossia, german, shorthands

When setting the language for polyglossia to German, one runs into trouble with the `quotes` library from `TikZ`: Handing over a label to the angle `pic` as suggested on page 511 in the `pgfmanual` fails when the whole `tikzpicture` is used as `newcommand` argument.

I give three examples below: The first works as expected (`tikzpicture` is not used inside a macro), the second throws an error (using it inside a macro), the third tried to circumvent the problem by using the `text=` option but results in no label for the angle.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{german}
\newcommand{\figC}[1]{\begin{center}#1\end{center}}

\begin{document}

This one works due to 'quotes' library:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}\shorthandoff{"}
\draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C)
    pic ["$\alpha$", draw] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

This one throws an error:
\figC{\begin{tikzpicture}\shorthandoff{"}
\draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C)
    pic ["$\alpha$", draw] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}}

This one compiles but does not show the label (using 'text=' as I understood from pgfmanual p. 511):
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C)
    pic [text={$\alpha$}, draw] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compilation result]

The questions are:

- Should I file this somewhere as a bug, or is it my fault?
- Can I somehow protect the `tikzpicture` when I want to use it inside a macro?
- Or are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third example you have to use `pic text` instead only `text`. Options for the angle label can be added using `pic text options`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{german}
\newcommand{\figC}[1]{\begin{center}#1\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C)
    pic [pic text={$\alpha$},draw] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (1,1) coordinate (C)
    pic [pic text={$\alpha$},pic text options={red,font=\tiny}, draw] {angle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]